# How to I modify the order of data from one model using the data of another model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a list of conversations displayed on a page. Each of those conversations are full of messages between 2 users.

A conversation has_one message (master message which acts as a parent to the other messages of that conversation). The list of conversations are currently ordered like this:

```
default_scope :order => 'conversations.updated_at DESC'
```

I'd prefer for the list to be ordered using the most recently posted messages created_at or updated_at time/date. To get to the most recently posted message I could do this

```
c = Conversation.find(4)
c.message.children.last
```

Then from there I could get access to the columns I want. Below is what I'm currently have. Is there a way to tweak this so it accesses my Messages table and gets the created_at and updated_at data from the message that has just been posted and uses that to order the Conversation list mentioned above?

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :message

   default_scope :order => 'conversations.updated_at DESC'



class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_tree
  has_one :conversation
```

Kind regards

Comment: Can you add your model and association definitions? I think we're missing something based on "c.message.children..." and "message_threads.updated at..."  I don't think the solution you need will be difficult, I just want to ensure you get the right info.

Comment: Hi sorry message_threads should have said conversations. I've corrected this.

Comment: No problem.  Just to be clear -- the way this is setup shows the conversation to message relationship as one-to-one. A conversation associates to one message and a message has only one conversation. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep this is correct. Each message has children which make up the conversation. The very first message is the one used to identify the conversation. It has a parent_id which is the message_id in the conversations table/model.

Comment: Well, I was wrong when I said "I don't think the solution will be difficult", since these associations actually make it quite difficult along with the self-referencing message association that can theoretically go n-levels deep. I'd agree with boulder's direction that he's stated in his answers and comments -- but that would require a schema update.  Sorry to leave you short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want you'll need to join the messages table, group by conversation id and order by an aggregated function of updated_at. 
Translated to Rails, something like:

```
default_scope { select("conversations.*, max(messages.updated_at) as last_update").join(:messages).group("conversations.id").order("last_update desc") }
```

I am assuming Rails 3, although your first definition of default_scope seems to indicate Rails 2. If so, you'll have to modify my code accordingly.

Comment: @LondonGuy. I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post; but I found an inconsistency. You say that conversation has many messages but your code says Conversation belongs_to :message. I don't think you can build the query you want with that configuration in pure sql.

Comment: I should have said a conversation has_one message (master message) and that master message is the parent to all the other messages of that conversation.

Comment: Is that something you are able to change? I would put a foreign key to the conversation in every message. If you want the parent message you can do easily with where(:parent_id => nil). This way my solution is applicable. Otherwise I am afraid pure sql won't cut it.